# Unable to connect to the remote server error using ChromeDriver v2.22.0

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, server

I have seen some answers about this subject but were from a couple of years ago and the answer revolved around using a localhost and or using selenium server which I am not doing either.

I am using a combination of SpecFlow, Selenium, and NUnit for my automation project.  I use the ReSharper Unit Test Explorer which runs the SpecFlow scenarios.

The test scenario I currently have is filling out text fields and saving the entry.

There is an AfterScenario that gets ran after each scenario that performs Driver.Quit() and it appears that the instance is destroyed then reinitialized as the next scenario runs.

I can run the scenarios individually and they run perfectly fine. The is comes when I attempt to run the scenarios as a collection, where one runs after another. The tests that run are the same text entry scenarios and the first scenario runs successfully but when the second scenario gets to the first text entry field, this error occurs.

(note: I am not running these tests on a local host, they are being ran in a development environment)

Additional information: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [::1]:63961

at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)

at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)

Code:

```
    class EliteLoginSteps
public EliteTest newTest; 
    [BeforeScenario()]                                                 
    public void Setup()
    {
       if (newTest == null)
        {
            newTest = new EliteTest();
            newTest.Init();
        }
        else
        {
            newTest.Cleanup();
        }         
    }                        
    [AfterScenario()]
    public void PostTestTearDown()
        {
            newTest.Cleanup();
            Console.WriteLine("Test Complete");
        }

    EliteTest class
        public void Init()
        {
        //init driver
        Driver.Initialize();
        }
        public void Cleanup()
        {
        Driver.Close()
        }

    Driver class
        public static IWebDriver Instance { get; set; }
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            //set browser driver type
            switch (TestManager.EnvironmentBrowserType.ToLower())
            {
                case ("chrome"):                    
                    Instance = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
                case ("ie"):
                    Instance = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    break;
                case ("firefox"):
                    Instance = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
                default:
                    Instance = new FirefoxDriver();
                    break;
            }
        }
        public static void Close()
            {
                Instance.Quit();
            }
```

Comment: You should probably share some code from your before scenario and after scenario as it's probably related to your setup there. Is your driver a static instance by any chance?

Comment: @SamHolder, I added the code and yes the driver is a static instance.

Comment: where do you call the `Init()` method of your elite class?

Comment: We use specflow, so the Init() is called everytime the First Login step occurs. Ex.  Given I am logged in. The first thing the method does is 'newTest.Init()'    (note: it occurs in the same class as the before and after scenarios)

Comment: why not do it in the before scenario?

Comment: I do prefer that, so I moved it there, however, I still get the error when running the tests back to back.

Comment: have you put break points on all your driver initialise/quit locations and checked that you are not using the driver after you have quit?

Comment: Yes, I just went through it and there are is no driver use after the quit. The test moves on to the next scenario which would then calls before scenario and initializes the driver again.  I really am at a loss.  It only occurs on the second scenario that tries to populate a text entry field.  The wrapped driver on the element that I am attempting to sendkeys to loses it's connection.

Comment: I would create a console app to test the behaviour. Create a driver instance and initialise it, then use it and then reassign it to a new one and try and use that, see what happens. Basically remove as much of the infrastructure from the issue as you can to see if you can still replicate the issue, then it might be easier to fix.

Comment: I figured it out.  We are using page object model for our selenium framework and within the pageClass that the text entry was occurring I had a private static iwebelement _name variable.  I also set that variable with Driver.Instance.FindElement(by.xpath(...));  The second go round it causes the error.  So i created a public get method to return that variable and it worked.